# Rails 5.2: Requiring ActiveRecord from an initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, initializer

I have in my `initializers/my_initializer.rb`:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractMysqlAdapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:string] = {
  name: 'varchar',
  limit: 191
}
```

Why does it throw the error: `uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractMysqlAdapter (NameError)` when I try to start the server?

I get the same error even if I put the following in the 1st line of the initializer:

```
require 'active_record'
```

However, when I put the below statement in the 1st line of the initializer, everything works fine:

```
require '/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb'
```

Why does it not work with `require 'active_record'`?

Comment: I'm guessing ActiveRecord does not require the mysql adaptar by default since you may not want to use MySQL as the database adaptar (like, you want pg for example).

Comment: @arieljuod Thanks. Assuming this is the only issue, I assume the correct way to require the mysql adapter would be:  `require 'active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb'`?

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure if it is or isn't the correct way, but I guess it's ok if it works. You can skip the ".rb" extension on the require.